# Why does Minimize fail to optimize the Lagrangian?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

When trying to solve an constrained optimization problem why does `Minimize` fail to solve the Lagrangian? From my understanding, optimizing a $N$ dimensional function with $m$ equality constraints can be reduced to an unconstrained $N+m$ dimension optimization by using a Lagrangian.

Suppose the problem is setup to minimize,

$$f(x,y) = x^2 y$$

with one constraint

$$g(x,y) := x^2 + y^2 = 1.$$

The Lagrangian would then be

$$\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda) = x^2 y - \lambda \,(x^2 + y^2 -1).$$

The point now is to optimize the Lagrangian or find the extrema of the Lagrangian, $\nabla \mathcal{L} = 0$. I would think that asking to minimize the Lagrangian would return the answer

```
Minimize[x^2 y - λ (x^2 + y^2 - 1), {x, y, λ}]
```

However, whatever this solves does not satisfy the constraint that

$$\partial_\lambda \mathcal{L} = 0.$$

The solution can be found by explicitly

```
Solve[D[x^2 y - λ (x^2 + y^2 - 1), {{x, y, λ}}] == 0, {x, y, λ}]
```

or

```
Minimize[{x^2 y, x^2 + y^2 == 1}, {x, y}]
```

Going off the diagram [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationIntroduction.html#248488806), I would have thought `Minimize` is the right tool for the job; however, none of the methods work.

Comment: What you might want are the roots of the gradient of the Lagrangian. Not the minimization, since it is not the objective function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You assume that minimizers of the constraint problem were related to minimizers of the Lagrangian. But your particular problem is a counterexample.

The triple $(x,y,\lambda)$ that solves the KKT-conditions is only a *critical* point of $\mathcal{L}$. As you can easily verify, your Lagrangian is not bounded from below: For $x = y = 0$, you get arbitrarily small values for $\mathcal{L}(0,0,\lambda)$ if you use sufficiently small (negative) $\lambda$. And indeed, Mathematica tries to tell you that by returning

```
(* {-\[Infinity], {x -> 0, y -> 0, \[Lambda] -> -\[Infinity]}} *)
```

along with the error message

```
(* Minimize::natt: The minimum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints. *)
```

So, if the minimizer of a constrained optimization problem is not related to a minimizer of the Lagrangian (which happens, e.g., when the constrained optimization problem has a minimum but the Lagrangian has not), it is not meaningful to look for minimizers of $\mathcal{L}$. Instead, you should look for roots of the total derivative of $\mathcal{L}$, e.g., with `FindRoot`.

Maybe you mean the [*augmented* Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Lagrangian_method)? However, that's quite a different story.

Comment: Which assumption? I see now that `Minimize[]` is a global method, and so I suppose I was bound to fail as you mentioned. Interestingly, for methods that find local extrema, I must start extremely near the solution for it finds the local extrema I seek: `FindMinimum[
 x^2 y - \[Lambda] (x^2 + y^2 - 1), {{x, -Sqrt[(2/3)] - .00001^2}, {y,
    -Sqrt[1/3] - .00001^2}, {\[Lambda], -Sqrt[1/3] - .00001^2}}]`. This probably has something to do with the function itself.